# ini4j accessing files else where and reading

Tags: java, maven, ini4j

Let me start off by saying I know some C programming and have never touched java before. (took me a bit to get maven to function). I have an .ini file stored in Appdata -> roaming -> testfolder -> file.ini the sections are handled like this

```
[#mishap.username]
Data=#

[#mishap.username2]
Data=#
```

string sender has the username stored when called by that specific user.

So my question is how do I go about accessing an ini file in that directory path outside of the program? I can't even test to see if I can use the string as part of the section until I have this sorted. Again sorry if this is basic, every tutorial I have looked at shows the ini file being accessed locally and I have tried to include file path with crashes during compile. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Use an absolute path.
`File file = new File("C:/Users/someuser/AppData/Roaming/somefilder/somefile.ext");`

Comment: I have tried Wini ini = new Wini(new File("C:/Users/user/AppData/Roaming/testfolder/file.ini")); and when I compile it in maven I get symbol errors. I have included import org.ini4j.Ini;
import org.ini4j.Profile.Section;
I have also edited my pom file for maven to include ini4j

Comment: Make sure youre actually including ini4j in the projects dependencies

Comment: This is my .xml http://pastebin.com/rm4VKb7r
and the imports in djservice.java http://pastebin.com/UFxNYDaZ

Comment: Strange, try specifying ini4j specifically for the shade includes

Comment: I have no idea how to do this.